# How do I make the font size in the table adaptive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a form now, and the number of words in the form is different.Now assume that the table size does not change and I want the font size in the table to change with the number of words.That is to say, the more words, the smaller the font and  the last words, the bigger the front. Could you please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but you could use javascript.  Example below:

```
var allTDs = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for (i=0; i<allTDs.length; i++){

    var tdLength = allTDs[i].innerText.length;

    if (tdLength<=100){
        allTDs[i].style.fontSize="large";
    } else if (tdLength>100 && tdLength<=200){
        allTDs[i].style.fontSize="medium";
    } else if (tdLength>200 && tdLength<=400){
        allTDs[i].style.fontSize="small";
    } else if (tdLength>400){
        allTDs[i].style.fontSize="x-small";
    };
};
```

Note:  This example counts the number of characters in the innerText instead of the number of words.  You could change it to count words instead - one way to get a rough count of words is to actually count the spaces " " in the innerText:

```
var tdLength = allTDs[i].innerText.split(" ").length;
```